# On wordpress.com how to set a category as front page?

Tags: wordpress.com

I first referred to a [link](http://en.support.wordpress.com/pages/front-page/) explaining how to set a page as your front page. What I want is to set a category of my blogs as my front page display.

Hoping for an answer, I went to the following link:
http://en.forums.wordpress.com/topic/1-category-as-front-page?replies=4

It effectively redirects me to my first link. Though I can make a page on wordpress.com and set it as my front page, I still haven't understood how to set one of my blog categories as my front display.

Answer (score -1):

This plug-in worked for me:
[Frontpage Category Filter](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/frontpage-category-filter/)

After you install it, go to Settings > Frontpage Category Filter, then choose which category or categories you want displayed on your frontpage.

Just for reference, with this plugin your frontpage is still using your index.php file (not the archive.php file that is normally used with categories).

Comment: OP doesn't have self-hosted WordPress. You can't add plugins at wordpress.com.